# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: TypeError: ban() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reason'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have seen other bots use the =reason argument in ban() but it doesn't work for me. I want the reason to show up in Discord's server logs (in the ban list) rather than mine. Example code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, banreason: str):
await client.ban(member, delete_message_days=7, reason=banreason)
```

Answer (score 1):

`client.ban` does not have a `reason` parameter when using the latest release of `discord.py`, see documentation: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.ban

However, the rewrite branch does contain the `reason` parameter.
http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.ban

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `reason` parameter is only supported on Discord.py v1.0. The entire library has been rewritten, and that's essentially the newest version.

Unfortunately, the syntax has changed a lot (functions moved from Client to states, etc), but if you have the time, rewriting your bot to 1.0 would be the best option.

[Here's](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1036) the related Github issue. And [here's](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.ban) the rewritten API docs for 1.0.